# How to see who has seen a post in my Facebook group - I have under 250 members and can no longer see you saw the post

Tags: facebook

How to see who has seen a post in my Facebook group - I have under 250 members and I use to be able to see this now I can't see who viewed the post although the "seen by" is still there it's just grayed out